# WiFi not working in Backtrack 5r3 Acer Aspire V3-571 Laptop having “Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ether” integrated wireless card

Tags: wifi, backtrack

I have installed backtrack 5r3 in one hard disk partition alongside with windows7 in another partition in Acer Aspire V3-571 laptop having "Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ether" integrated wireless card.

My problem is I could not make WiFi working in my laptop even after trying a lot of command and methods found by googling. I downloaded tg3 driver from broadcom website and hopefully installed it but all in vain.

In some forum I found that some guys having the same issue with Broadcom 43XXX seriers wireless card had fixed their issue by using some sta driver package by broadcom specific for 43XXX series, but I noticed I have 57XXX series wireless card not the same.

I could not find any working solution for BCM57785 wireless card.

Here's what I did......

```
root@bt:~# cd /lib/firmware
root@bt:/lib/firmware# unzip linux-3.133d.zip
Archive:  linux-3.133d.zip
creating: Server/Linux/Driver/
inflating: Server/Linux/Driver/ChangeLog  
inflating: Server/Linux/Driver/README.TXT  
inflating: Server/Linux/Driver/tg3-3.133d-1.src.rpm  
inflating: Server/Linux/Driver/tg3-3.133d.tar.gz  
inflating: Server/Linux/Driver/tg3_sup-3.133d-1.ISO.tar.gz  
root@bt:/lib/firmware# 

root@bt:/lib/firmware# rpm -ivh tg3-3.133d.src.rpm
The program 'rpm' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install rpm

root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# apt-get install rpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libecryptfs0 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libdebconfclient0 ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup
rdate bogl-bterm libdebian-installer4 reiserfsprogs dmraid python-pyicu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
librpmbuild0 rpm2cpio
Suggested packages:
alien elfutils rpm-i18n
The following NEW packages will be installed:
librpmbuild0 rpm rpm2cpio
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,164kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,818kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 ................ revolution/main librpmbuild0 4.7.2-1lbuild1 [716kB]
Get:2............ revolution/main rpm2cpio 4.7.2-1lbuild1 [651kB]
Get:3 .................. revolution/main rpm 4.7.2-1lbuild1 [797kB]
Fetched 2,164kB in 27s (77.4kB/s)                                              
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package librpmbuild0.
(Reading database ... 264111 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking librpmbuild0 (from .../librpmbuild0_4.7.2-1lbuild1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package rpm2cpio.
Unpacking rpm2cpio (from .../rpm2cpio_4.7.2-1lbuild1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package rpm.
Unpacking rpm (from .../rpm_4.7.2-1lbuild1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up librpmbuild0 (4.7.2-1lbuild1) ...

Setting up rpm2cpio (4.7.2-1lbuild1) ...
Setting up rpm (4.7.2-1lbuild1) ...
Trying rpm init...

Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# rpm -ivh tg3-3.133d.src.rpm
rpm: please use alien to install rpm packages on Debian, if you are really sure use --                force-debian switch. See README.Debian for more details.
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# rpm -ivh tg3-3.133d.src.rpm --force-debian
error: open of tg3-3.133d.src.rpm failed: No such file or directory
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# rpm -ivh tg3-3.133d.src.rpm
rpm: please use alien to install rpm packages on Debian, if you are really sure use --   force-debian switch. See README.Debian for more details.
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# cd
root@bt:~# apt-get update
Fetched 7,978kB in 1min 54s (69.6kB/s)                                         
Reading package lists... Done
root@bt:~# apt-get install alien
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libecryptfs0 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libdebconfclient0 ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup
rdate bogl-bterm libdebian-installer4 reiserfsprogs dmraid python-pyicu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
debhelper html2text
Suggested packages:
lsb-rpm lintian dh-make
The following NEW packages will be installed:
alien debhelper html2text
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
Need to get 650kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,991kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 .................. revolution/main html2text 1.3.2a-14build1 [104kB]
Get:2 ..................... revolution/main debhelper 7.4.15ubuntu1 [461kB]
Get:3 ....................... revolution/main alien 8.79ubuntu0.1 [85.4kB]
Fetched 650kB in 11s (55.7kB/s)                                                
Selecting previously deselected package html2text.
(Reading database ... 264205 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking html2text (from .../html2text_1.3.2a-14build1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package debhelper.
Unpacking debhelper (from .../debhelper_7.4.15ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package alien.
Unpacking alien (from .../alien_8.79ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up html2text (1.3.2a-14build1) ...

Setting up debhelper (7.4.15ubuntu1) ...
Setting up alien (8.79ubuntu0.1) ...
root@bt:~# alien -k tg3-3.133d-1.src.rpm
File "tg3-3.133d-1.src.rpm" not found.
root@bt:~# cd /lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# alien -k tg3-3.133d-1.src.rpm
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
tg3_3.133d-1_amd64.deb generated
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# alien -k tg3-3.133d-1.src.rpm
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
tg3_3.133d-1_amd64.deb generated
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# dpkg tg3-3.133d-1.src.deb
dpkg: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
Type dpkg --license for copyright license and lack of warranty (GNU GPL) [*].

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# dpkg -i tg3-3.133d-1.src.deb
dpkg: error processing tg3-3.133d-1.src.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
tg3-3.133d-1.src.deb
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# dpkg -i tg3_3.133d-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously deselected package tg3.
(Reading database ... 264518 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking tg3 (from tg3_3.133d-1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up tg3 (3.133d-1) ...
root@bt:~# cd /lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver
root@bt:/lib/firmware/Server/Linux/Driver# tar xvzf tg3-3.133d.tar.gz
tg3-3.133d/
tg3-3.133d/tg3.h
tg3-3.133d/tg3_vmware.h
tg3-3.133d/README.TXT
tg3-3.133d/ChangeLog
tg3-3.133d/tg3_vmware.c
tg3-3.133d/tg3_compat2.h
tg3-3.133d/tg3_compat.h
tg3-3.133d/tg3.c
tg3-3.133d/LICENSE
tg3-3.133d/makeflags.sh
tg3-3.133d/tg3_firmware.h
tg3-3.133d/tg3.4
tg3-3.133d/esx_ioctl.h
tg3-3.133d/Makefile

root@bt:/lib/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# insmod tg3.ko
insmod: error inserting 'tg3.ko': -1 File exists
root@bt:/lib/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# modprobe tg3
root@bt:/lib/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# cd
root@bt:~# cd /lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# insmod tg3.koinsmod:    error inserting 'tg3.ko': -1 File exists
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# modprobe tg3
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# cd src
bash: cd: src: No such file or directory
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# make KVER=3.2.6
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# insmod tg3
insmod: can't read 'tg3': No such file or directory
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised link modes:  Not reported
Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
Speed: Unknown!
Duplex: Unknown! (255)
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
Link detected: no
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom# cd
root@bt:~# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised link modes:  Not reported
Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
Speed: Unknown!
Duplex: Unknown! (255)
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
Link detected: no
root@bt:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

root@bt:~# 


root@bt:~# iwconfig
ppp0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

root@bt:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:0a:0f:67  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:16 

      lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:9829 (9.8 KB)  TX bytes:9829 (9.8 KB)

       ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:101.218.175.244  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3531 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:3296893 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:390972 (390.9 KB)

root@bt:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM     Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor     Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2  (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet   PCIe (rev 10)
02:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Memory Card Reader (rev 10)
02:00.2 System peripheral: Broadcom Corporation Device 16be (rev 10)
02:00.3 System peripheral: Broadcom Corporation Device 16bf (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
root@bt:~# airmon-ng


Interface   Chipset     Driver


root@bt:~# cd /lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# insmod tg3.ko
insmod: error inserting 'tg3.ko': -1 File exists

root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# modprobe tg3
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# 
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# lsmod | grep tg3.ko
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# lsmod | grep tg3
tg3                   147905  0 
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# sudo modprobe wl
FATAL: Module wl not found.
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# sudo modprobe wl
FATAL: Module wl not found.
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net# sudo modprobe tg3
root@bt:/lib64/modules/3.2.6/kernel/drivers/net#
```

Comment: BCM57785 is not a wi-fi card, it's an Ethernet card.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to swapping out the wifi cards?  I have spent whole days trying to install broadcom drivers, but only succeeded once.  If I understood at the time that I could spend like $15 and save myself many hours of frustration, I would have.  I have had good luck with the atheros 9k-series, they've always worked out-of-the-box.

If you decide to take this route, just make sure that your bios doesn't have a "whitelist", meaning that it won't boot your OS unless you have the stock hardware in place.  I have both HP and Lenovo laptops with this, but my Acer laptop doesn't.  After a preliminary googling, I don't *think* yours does either, but that's no guarantee.